# Passing html values into javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a javascript function in which I need to confirm the input. I wrote the following code but its giving negative value i.e. "else" part even if i enter a valid value. Can some one please suggest a solution?

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Javascript App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app1.js">

</script>
</head>
<body><h1 id="heading1" style="text-align:center; height:auto; width:auto; font-family:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif">Determinant of a nxn matrix</h1> 
<p id="paragraph1" style="font-family:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif"> This program allows you to compute the determinant of a nxn matrix</p>

<p>
Input the order of the matrix
<br />

<input type="text" maxlength="3" name="value" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="verifyorder(value)" />
</p>
<p id="error"></p>
<p id="detspace"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Javascript File:

```
function verifyorder(order){
;
    if(order>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("Sorry, you need to enter a positive integer value, try again");
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Sorry, you need to enter a positive integer value, try again"; 

    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted clearly runs *after* the problems occurs.  My guess is that you have passed in a *string*, not a number, but without the code calling `verifyorder` I can't tell.

Comment: There is nothing in your code which associates the (undefined and uninitialised) Javascript variable called "value" with a DOM element which happens to have the name "value". You need in some way to tell the Javascript to find that input element and extract its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VcRqt/1/)

I changed your HTML and give your input textfield an id of value.  I removed the passed param for your verifyorder function, and instead grab the content of your textfield by using document.getElementById(); then i convert the str into value with `+order` so you can check if it's greater than zero:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" name="value" id='value' />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="verifyorder()" />
</p>
<p id="error"></p>
<p id="detspace"></p> 

function verifyorder() {
        var order = document.getElementById('value').value;
        if (+order > 0) {
            alert(+order);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Sorry, you need to enter a positive integer value, try again");
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Sorry, you need to enter a positive integer value, try again";
        }
    }
```

Comment: how if I want to bring param to the javascripts? `javascript: somefunc(someparams);` like this?

Answer (score 23):

Give the textbox an id of "txtValue" and change the input button declaration to the following:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="verifyorder(document.getElementById('txtValue').value)" />
```

Comment: The better answer here, which makes use of the function's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put id attribute in your input text field -

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" name="value" id="value" />
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:  `if(parseInt(order)>0){....`